# Install QGIS with the GRASS plugin enabled in a conda environment?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-grass-plugin

I am having issues using the GRASS plugin in QGIS in a PyQGIS script. I used miniconda on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS to create an env with QGIS using conda commands:

```
conda create -n qgis_test
conda activate qgis_test
conda install -c conda-forge qgis
```

This gives me QGIS 3.32.0. Then I try to access QGIS and one of the grass algorithms using:

```
import qgis.core
import processing
processing.core.Processing.Processing.initialize()
processing.algorithmHelp('grass7:r.watershed')
```

The QGIS loads fine but I get the following error for grass7:

```
Error: Algorithm grass7:r.watershed not found
```

When I open QGIS GUI from the conda env, I can see that under Processing Toolbox (on the right panel)>Options>Providers, the GRASS options are not available. So I have confirmed that my conda installation of QGIS does not have the GRASS plugin by default.

How can I install the plugin now or install QGIS from scratch with GRASS enabled?